# How to use system variable @@dataset_id in BigQuery view

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery has session-bound (or script-bound) system variables, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/system-variables). Within a session, I can declare the value of one of those variables, e.g. with something like:

```
set @@dataset_id = 'my_dataset_id';
```

Now, I'd like to have a view (which I plan on running within a session) that includes something like:

```
create view foo
as
select ...
from @@dataset_id.my_table
```

... this doesn't work. Nor does any form of quoting around that variable. It appears use of that variable simply isn't allowed to help identify the namespace of `my_table`.

If that's true, I'm struggling to see the value of that variable at all. Does anyone know if I can use those variables as so, or how to prevent needing to namespace-bound all instances of `my_table`? I'd like to manage these query scripts outside of BQ itself, and ideally without templating in everywhere (e.g. `{dataset_id}.my_table`)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your concern,
Please try below:

```
set @@dataset_id = "SampleDataSetID";

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
CREATE VIEW sampleView1 as (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    %s.sampleTable
  
);
""", @@dataset_id);
```

I used `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the sql dynamically ( using the variable that we set to the session.)

Output:
[image]

[image]